# Сохранение объектов

Tags: java, android, хранение-данных

Начал писать первое, что пришло в голову - книгу с рецептами.
Суть в том, что на главном экране расположен `ListView` с заголовками и кнопка "добавить". При нажатии на "добавить", открывается другое активити, в котором вводится название рецепта и его описание. Из этих данных создается новый объект:

```
public class Recipe implements Parcelable{
private String recipeName;
private String recipeDescriptions;

public Recipe(String recipeName, String recipeDescriptions) {
    this.recipeName = recipeName;
    this.recipeDescriptions = recipeDescriptions;
   }
} //дальше реализация Parcelable
```

При нажатии на `Item` в `ListView` должно происходить редактирование этого рецепта. На данный момент реализовано новое `Activity`, в которое передаются recipeName и recipeDescriptions и заносятся в соответствующие `EditText`'ы. Все редактируется и сохраняется прекрасно. Однако, когда встал вопрос о сохранении объектов, для их восстановления при загрузке приложения, меня просто заклинило. Неужели тут нельзя обойтись без БД? Я думаю, что меня понесло не в ту степь.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильнее всего реализовать хранение и восстановление при загрузке? Может быть мне нужно полностью пересмотреть концепцию приложения и все делать каким-либо другим способом? Может вовсе не нужно делать класс `Recipe`, а все делать `String`'ами?

Comment: Лучше всего в БД класть. Можете взять `NoSql` решения от `Realm` - оно модное и крутое. Хранить можно прямо объекты, никакой возни с SQL`.

Comment: Если всё, что у Вас есть -- это просто единственная коллекция из объектов, то Вы можете просто сериализовать их в JSON и сохранить файлик в приватном хранилище. В целом согласен с предыдущим комментарием: Realm крайне просто подключить и использовать.

Comment: А не случится такого, что при открытии приложения с 200 рецептами, начнут создаваться 200 объектов и все будет висеть?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, `RecyclerView` умеет работать со сложными и массивными списками лучше, чем `ListView`, используйте лучше его, он еще и удобнее. С ним висеть точно не будет

Comment: Вашу модель `Recipe` можно заменить на `Pair<String, String>`, но так хуже... Лучше ведь брать название через `getRecipeName`

Comment: @R1zen Случится, но ничего в этом страшного нет, то же самое произойдёт, если вы будете работать с базой данных. Ну разве что если вы не собираетесь каждый раз вычитывать данные из курсора, что неудобно в большинстве реальных ситуаций.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за ответы. Пока выбрал вариант с использованием SQLite, в перспективе хочу переделать с помощью Realm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть 4 варианта:

1. Сохранять данные в `SharedPreferences` - способ для бедных, когда надо сохранять чуть-чуть и немного
2. Самый правильный способ сохранять в БД, стандартный в SQLite более моднявый способ через [Realm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realm_(database))
3. Можно использовать различные облачные варианты - самый родной для Android облачный сервис [FireBase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase#Realtime_Database)
4. Есть и четвертый вариант, воспользоваться стандартным механизмом Java реализуемым через интерфейс `Serializable` чтение/запись через `ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream` - с записью на внешний файл в `Context.getFilesDir()` - не рекомендую.